# P value for Markov table

Tags: r, markov-process

I have the following two-state Markov chain:

```
pre<-cbind(c(rep("rain",100),rep("sun",100),rep("rain",100)))
post<-cbind(c(rep("rain",50),rep("sun",70),rep("rain",100),rep("sun",80)))
df<-cbind(pre,post)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)<-c("pre","post")

states<-c("rain","sun")

probsCase<-function(i,j){
sum(as.character(df$pre)==states[i] & as.character(df$post)==states[j])/sum(as.character(df$pre)==states[i])
}

transitionMatrix<-outer(1:2,1:2,Vectorize(probsCase))
colnames(transitionMatrix)<-states
rownames(transitionMatrix)<-states

library(diagram)
plotmat(t(transitionMatrix),relsize=0.75)
```

...that produces the following plot:
[image]

Is there something like a p value for this model that I can add to the plot? Something that would show whether the model differs significantly from, say, another hypothetical model where there are no differences in probabilities from one state to the other? For example, from the plot wec can discern that after each sunny day, there is 20% chance of another sunny day and 80% chance of a rainy day. How do I know whether this 20/80 differs from 50/50 significantly (p value would be <0.05) or by chance (p>0.05).

I did run `chisq.test(transitionMatrix)` with the resulting value of 1 but I don't think that's the correct way to test the model.

Comment: (1) The plot cannot be correct, because the sum of weights of outgoing arrows is not unity.  (2) Since your data are not given in the form they would naturally take if you had observed a sequence of transitions, what exactly do they represent?

Comment: @whuber weights of ingoing arrows equals 1. To make outgoing arrows to equal one, this can be achieved by transposing the transition matrix that is being plotted: `t(transitionMatrix)`. So for example, after each sunny day, there is 20% chance of another sunny day and 80% chance of a rainy day. How do I know whether this 20/80 differs from 50/50 significantly (p value would be <0.05) or by chance (p>0.05).

Comment: The arrows conventionally point in the direction of transitions rather than against them.  Since people will look at the plot rather than try to decipher your code, it would help to make the plot accurate--or at least include an explanation of how you intend it to be read.  In a similar vein, it would be better to explain your data and your calculations in English rather than relying on the code to reveal them.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the suggestion, I updated the post accordingly